# Ansible: copying the value from one file to other based on a condition

Tags: loops, split, ansible

I've tried a lot many ways to get this done in Ansible, I still get stuck :/

So,  I have to read credentials (user & password) from one file:

file1:  (dest: /home/usr/Desktop/file1.txt)

```
#this is a cred file
number= 8910334
user= xyz  #(this maybe username=xyz also)
password= abc
```

After reading the file content, I need to split where ever I find a ('=') sign  with 'user' & 'password' based on the following:

user key= user

user value= xyz

password key= password

password value= abc

file2: (dest: /home/usr/Desktop/file2.txt)

```
#Hi, I need credentials
school= spsg
user =         #(this value may be blank or may be filled with some other entry or it may be xyz.user.name=   )
password=    #(this value may be blank or may be filled with some other entry or it may be xyz.password.value= )
```

Now, in file2, I want the user=________ value & password=________ value replaced by the extracted  user value  & password value from file1. (the line number of user & password may vary, so don't fix the line numbers as [1] & [2] respectively)

Also, along with file2, there are some more files which need the values from file1, so it would be better if this task is done with loops.

Please suggest me with possible YAML code for getting this done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not local [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/fetch_module.html) it. Then the task below

```yaml
  vars:
    file_name: file1.txt
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|default([]) +
                     [{'key': item, 'value': my_value}] }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('pipe', my_cat).splitlines()|
                select('match', my_regex_comment)|
                map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                map('trim')|
                list }}"
      vars:
        my_regex_comment: '^(?!\s*\#).*$'  # filter commented line
        my_regex_any_comment: '(\s*\#.*)'  # match comment in value
        my_regex: '^(.*?)=(.*)$'           # match key and value
        my_replace: '\1'                   # replace with key
        my_replace_empty: ""               # delete
        my_cat: "{{ 'cat ' ~ file_name }}"
        my_ini: "{{ item ~ ' type=properties file=' ~ file_name }}"
        my_value: "{{ lookup('ini', my_ini)|
                      regex_replace(my_regex_any_comment, my_replace_empty) }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_vars
```

gives

```
  my_vars:
  - key: number
    value: '8910334'
  - key: user
    value: xyz
  - key: password
    value: abc
```

Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) to write the file. For example the task and the template below

```yaml
    - template:
        src: file2.txt.j2
        dest: file2.txt
```

```
shell> cat file2.txt.j2
{% for item in my_vars %}
{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```sh
shell> cat file2.txt
number=8910334
user=xyz
password=abc
```

The next option is to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) to add, or replace the variables in the loop

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: file2.txt
        regex: '^\s*{{ item.key }}\s*=(.*)$'
        line: '{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}'
      loop: "{{ my_vars }}"
```